# python parallel input and outputs with pipeline

Tags: python

I want to build a python game that simultaneously takes input and prints output as a study project

#### The game:

The user is given a sentence. A timer counts down (with the count displayed), while the user tries to write the sentence backwards in the output.

if you type in the output correctly, the timer is extended 
the game ends if the timer runs out, or the input is incorrect

#### Thus far:

I've been going through the different modules I can find (subprocesses, parallel python, multiprocessing), but have gotten stuck at various points. The furthest I've gotten was with the [concurrent futures module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures). The only problem is that the lose scenarios aren't updating immediately (ie. you can run out of time and it doesn't tell you that you've lost)

I find my way a bit hacky, I thought `multiprocessing` would be the best way, but I got stuck early with async calling of timer and input functions

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

def timer(n, pipe):
    count = n
    # count down
    while count > 0 and not pipe.flag_lose:
        # add more time if flag has been raised
        if pipe.can_has_additional_time():
            count += 10

        count -= 1
        print(' '*10, end='\r') # hacky way to clear line when going from double to single digits
        print(count, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
    print()

def get_input(pipe):
    while not pipe.flag_lose:
        sentence = "I never should have started this project"
        print("Quick! Print this backwards:", sentence)
        answer = input("Your Answer: ")

        # validate
        if answer == sentence[::-1]:
            pipe.flag_additional_time = True
        else:
            print("Wrong!")
            pipe.flag_lose = True

class HackedPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        # end game when this is True
        self.flag_lose = False
        # give more time when this is True
        self.flag_additional_time = False

    def can_has_additional_time(self):
        '''
        giving this flag an accessor because it needs to reset
        '''
        if self.flag_additional_time:
            self.flag_additional_time = False
            return True
        return False # NO!

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    hacked_pipeline = HackedPipeline()
    input_task = executor.submit(get_input, hacked_pipeline)
    output_task = executor.submit(timer, n=10, pipe=hacked_pipeline)
```

p.s. the answer is `tcejorp siht detrats evah dluohs reven I` for c+p purposes